# How to export and import a conda environment without errors

Tags: python, conda

I exported a conda environment in this way:

`conda env export > environment.yml`´

Then commited and pulled the environment.yml file to the git repo.

From another computer I cloned the repo and then tried to create the conda environment:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

First I got a warning:

> Warning: you have pip-installed dependencies in your environment file,
> but you do not list pip itself as one of your conda dependencies.
> Conda may not use the correct pip to install your packages, and they
> may end up in the wrong place.  Please add an explicit pip dependency.
> I'm adding one for you, but still nagging you

I don't know why conda export does not include pip in the environment definition.

Then I got errors like wrong/unavailable versions of packages:

> es-core-news-sm==3.0.0 version not found

I just removed the version part and only left the name of the package and got it work with:

```
conda env update --prefix ./env --file environment.yml  --prune
```

Here additional details:
[image]

I would like to know how can I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`es-core-news-sm==3.0` does not exist on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/es-core-news-sm/#history), where only 3.1 and 2.3.1 are available, hence your error message.

This is of course something very specific to the environment that you have and the packages that you have installed. In your specific case, just removing the version can be a fix, but no guarantee that this will work in all cases.

As for the cause, I can only guess, but what I expect happened in your case is:

1. You installed `es-core-news-sm==3.0` to your environment
2. The developers of that package created a newer version and decided to delete the old version
3. Exporting the environment does correctly state that it contains `es-core-news-sm==3.0`
4. Creating an environment from the `.yaml` from step 3 fails, because the packe is not available any longer (see 2.)

An alternative (depending on your usecase) coul;d be to use `conda-pack`, which can create a packed version of your environment that you can then unpack. This only works though if the OS on the source and target machine are the same

Comment: The 3.0 version is not available in PyPI as you mentioned. There is a jumped from 2.3.1 to 3.1.0 there. In the github repo there are plenty of other versions. I guess they maintained only some of them in PyPI.